# override one of the existing function, how to handle the rest of the function?

Tags: magento2.4, function

HI I was reviewing the code.
Does :void mean ignore this function in my override?

example:

```
private function clearIndexTable(): void
```

When I do override, I copy the original file and modify. The original file has few functions, I only need to modify one of the function. So how do I handle the rest of the functions that doesn't need to be override? I did try to delete those functions that doesn't need to make any change and it breaks. Please help and suggest me what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

:void does not mean ignoring the function in your override.
return `void` means: "Allow functions to declare that they do not return anything at all".

I think you are talking about override methods from a parent method. When you would like to override a method, you only need to override this method, and if this method includes code calls to other `private` methods you have to copy the other private methods from the parent class to your override class too.

Ex:

In the parent class:

```
private function clearIndexTable(): void
{
    $indexTable = $this->getIndexTable();
    ....
}

private function getIndexTable(): string
{
    ....
}
```

In your override class, you have to copy the `getIndexTable` method too.